# Scrapy-Splash: Cannot click buttons with lua script

Tags: python, web-scraping, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am scraping data from grammy.com and I would like to expand tabs containing the information  related to Grammy Awards (Image enclosed below).

I wrote a lua script to go through and click all the buttons but there does not seem to be any change to the html I received. Here is the [sample page](https://www.grammy.com/artists/bruno-mars/5082) and the lua script is as follows:

```
function main(splash)
    assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
    splash:set_viewport_full()
    assert(splash:wait(1))
    local btn = splash:select_all('button[class^=cursor-pointer]')
    for key , value in pairs(btn) do
        value:click()
        splash:wait(2)
    end
    return {
        html = splash:html(),
        png = splash:png(),
    }
end
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[image: Image enclosed]

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same problem. The thing that I do see is that in order to click you need to use the method splash:mouse_click().

See sourch: https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-mouse-click

Good look with the same problem that I have :P.